# Normalizing faceted histograms separately in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, normalization, histogram, facet

My questions is similar to
[Normalizing y-axis in histograms in R ggplot to proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766856/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion)
but I'd like to add to it a bit.

In general, I have 6 histograms in a 2x3 facet design, and I'd like to normalize each of them separately. I'll try to make a sample data set here to give an idea:

```
hvalues=c(3,1,3,2,2,5,1,1,12,1,4,3)
season=c("fall","fall","fall","fall","winter","winter","winter","winter","summer","summer","summer","summer")
year=c("year 1","year 1","year 2","year 2","year 1","year 1","year 2","year 2","year 1","year 1","year 2","year 2")
group=c("fall year 1","fall year 1","fall year 2","fall year 2","winter year 1","winter year 1","winter year 2","winter year 2","summer year 1","summer year 1","summer year 2","summer year 2")
all=data.frame(hvalues,season,year)
```

Using

```
ggplot(all, aes(x=hvalues,group=group)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
facet_grid(season ~ year)
```

gives the proportions overall (i.e. combining all the facets). I'd like each group facet to be normalized to 1. hvalues are not integers in my actual data - they are numerical.

I am a novice using R, and would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `y = ..density..`.

Comment: `all` has to be a dataframe. Try `all <- as.data.frame(cbind(hvalues,season,year))`.

Comment: @JT85 I agree, but please don't encourage the use of `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` in place of `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: @joran I have played around with y=..density.. , but I don't think this is really what I want to convey in the figure. I am interested in proportions of home ranges falling into different size categories, within each season, and within each year. Also, running ..density.. gives y values up to 3.0, which I don't understand.

Comment: @JT85 I have edited the question to include your data.frame comment...I was quickly trying to come up with a dataset and automatically went to cbind!

Comment: The usual last resort is always to calculate the proportions yourself outside of ggplot.

Comment: And in any case, if you're plotting proportions within distinct categories, `geom_bar` with pre-computed proportions would probably be more appropriate anyway.

Comment: @joran could you give an example of using geom_bar?

Comment: @joran - really sorry for the confusion! I should have specified that hvalues was numerical

Comment: Check out `?stat_bin` and try the options there. I think maybe `..ncount..` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @joran this is almost it. but ..ncount.. seems to scale to one in each bin of the histogram

Comment: Sigh. Exactly. Scaling to 1 in each facet is precisely what you said you want. I'm moving on now.

Comment: yes, i wanted ppns to add to 1 within each facet. ..ncount.. is showing ppns that add to >1 in each facet. maybe i'm missing something here. sorry to have bothered you, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is:

```
ggplot(all, aes(x=hvalues)) +
    facet_grid(season ~ year,drop=T) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..]))
```

I stole this from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725339/percentage-on-y-lab-in-a-faceted-ggplot-barchart)

I feel your question might be a duplicate of that one by the way.

Comment: Does anyone know what docs describe `..PANEL..`? I see count etc listed in `?stat_bin` under "Computed Variables" section, but I don't know how to even start searching for help on PANEL. Also, this is neat.