# Dealing with different sample sizes for facet histograms in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I would like to make stacked (`facet_grid`) size histograms in ggplot2 by Year. The years have different sample sizes. I have not been able to get the `..density..` to produce correct proportions for each histogram bin. So, I've been using `..count..`/(sample size number). From my reading of the stat tranformations `..count..`, you cannot perform an operation with an object (e.g. nrow(data)). How can I get these stacked histograms with different sample sizes? The format in the code below would produce a figure that matches other figures for a report, which is why I would like to stick with ggplot2, but maybe there are other packages. Here is an example:

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(round(rnorm(121, 86, 28), 0))
colnames(d1) <- "Length"
d1$Year <- "2015"

d2 <- as.data.frame(round(rnorm(86, 70, 32), 0))
colnames(d2) <- "Length"
d2$Year <- "2016"

D <- rbind(d1, d2)

ggplot(D, aes(x = Length)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../nrow(D)), 
                 breaks=seq(0, 160, by = 3), 
                 col="black", 
                 fill="grey48", 
                 alpha = .8)+
  labs(title = "Size by Year", x = "Length", y = "frequency") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=16), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 95.25), 
             colour = "red", size = 1.3)+
  facet_grid(Year ~ .)
```

This part `..count../nrow(D)` won't work and needs the sample size for each year when I facet them `facet_grid(Year ~ .)`

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339204/normalizing-faceted-histograms-separately-in-ggplot2) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? You didn't specify what went wrong when you used `..density..`, but it seems like you just need to scale by the binwidth. `..density..` scales so that the total bar area is 1, meaning that each bar has height `..count.. / (n * binwidth)`. You just want the height to be `..count.. / n`, which is `..density.. * binwidth`. So set the binwidth manually (you should do this anyway) and multiply by it.

```r
set.seed(1234)
d1 <- as.data.frame(round(rnorm(121, 86, 28), 0))
colnames(d1) <- "Length"
d1$Year <- "2015"

d2 <- as.data.frame(round(rnorm(86, 70, 32), 0))
colnames(d2) <- "Length"
d2$Year <- "2016"

D <- rbind(d1, d2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(D, aes(x = Length)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.. * 5), binwidth = 5) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 95.25), colour = "red", size = 1.3) +
  facet_grid(Year ~ .) +
  labs(title = "Size by Year", x = "Length", y = "frequency") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 16),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: How do you choose binwidth? It changes the scale. I provided test data, but when I run this with my real data, the bin frequencies do not add up to 1. I also get an error: "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: binwidth, bins, 'stat_bin()' using 'bins = 30'. Pick better value with binwidth. I tried binwidths that varied by orders of magnitude and none of them made sense.

Comment: binwidth is not an aesthetic, it's a parameter of geom_histogram. Check your parentheses