# Normalizing y-axis in histograms in R ggplot to proportion by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

My question is very similar to [Normalizing y-axis in histograms in R ggplot to proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766856/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion), except that I have two groups of data of different size, and I would like that each proportion is relative to its group size instead of the total size.

To make it clearer, let's say I have two sets of data in a data frame:

```
dataA<-rnorm(100,3,sd=2)
dataB<-rnorm(400,5,sd=3)
all<-data.frame(dataset=c(rep('A',length(dataA)),rep('B',length(dataB))),value=c(dataA,dataB))
```

I can plot the two distributions together with:

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=value,fill=dataset))+geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,position='identity',binwidth=0.5)
```

and instead of the frequency on the Y axis I can have the proportion with:

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=value,fill=dataset))+geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),alpha=0.5,position='identity',binwidth=0.5)
```

But this gives the proportion relative to the total data size (500 points here): is it possible to have it relative to each group size?

My goal here is to make it possible to compare visually the proportion of values in a given bin between A and B, independently from their respective size. Ideas which differ from my original one are also welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Like this? [edited based on OP's comment]

[image]

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=value,fill=dataset))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=0.5*..density..),
                 alpha=0.5,position='identity',binwidth=0.5)
```

Using `y=..density..` scales the histograms so the area under each is 1, or `sum(binwidth*y)=1.` As a result, you would use `y = binwidth*..density..` to have y represent the fraction of the total in each bin. In your case, `binwidth=0.5`.

IMO this is a little easier to interpret:

[image]

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=value,fill=dataset))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=0.5*..density..),binwidth=0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~dataset,nrow=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually I don't think the density is equivalent to dividing by the counts by dataset, unless the bar width is 1 (see for example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766856/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion). In particular in my case I would like to read the percentage that a bin represents on the Y axis.

Comment: You're right - need to scale by binwidth. See my edits.

Comment: oh yes, of course! I didn't even realize that when I replied, I guess I was too focused on the version with `y=..count../sum(..count..)`.  Apparently with `..count../sum(..count..)` each count is divided by the total count, whereas in the case of `..density..` it is applied to each group independently: I still don't understand why, in case you have an idea?

Comment: I just ran into this issue. According to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3522, you may be able to do `aes(y = stat(density*width))`, which will achieve the same result but without needing to manually set the binwidth. It's still a little unclear whether this is *supposed* to be allowed however.