# How can I scale histogram between 0 and 1 in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(x=meanf,fill = "g", color="g"), alpha = 0.6,binwidth = 0.02)+
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x=meanf,fill = "b", color="b"), alpha = 0.4,binwidth = 0.02)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="N1", values=c("g" = "green", "b"="blue"), labels=c("b"="1", "g"="2")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="N2", values=c("g" = "green", "b"="blue"), labels=c("b"="1", "g"="2"))+
  theme_bw()+
  ggsave('temp.jpg')
```

I am getting the plot with histogram counts, but I want to scale it between 0 and 1. From this question [Normalizing y-axis in histograms in R ggplot to proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766856/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion) , I understand how to do it for one dataframe, but what if I'm using two dataframes, as in my question?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(y = ..ncount..,x=meanf,fill = "g", color="g"))
```

should do it.

If you want both histograms be normalized by the same divisor:

First get the y-range of the original histogram first. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object)

```
ggobj <- ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(x=meanf,fill = "g", color="g"), alpha = 0.6,binwidth = 0.02)+
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x=meanf,fill = "b", color="b"), alpha = 0.4,binwidth = 0.02)

y_max <- ggplot_build(ggobj)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range[2]
```

Then recreate your histogram and scale it with the y_range that you got.

```
p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(y_max=y_max, y=..count../y_max,x=meanf,fill = "g", color="g"), alpha = 0.6,binwidth = 0.02)+
      geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(y_max=y_max, y=..count../y_max,x=meanf,fill = "b", color="b"), alpha = 0.4,binwidth = 0.02)
```

Comment: When I divide by y_range, I am getting this error even though y_range exists: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y_range' not found

Comment: Alright, you can't use an environment variable with the special ggplot variables like `..count..`, so you need to redefine it in aes. I fixed the code, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the data first! Just create a temporary dataset that has its y-axis scaled between 0 and a certain number--divide everything by that certain number (if you want the top-most to be 1.00, set the divisor to the top number).

Comment: No need for a temporary dataset, you can provide an equation in the plot’s aesthetics.

Comment: @maximusdooku Apologies, I hadn’t seen the restriction of using two datasets - `..count.. / max(..count..)` only seems to work for a single one, which makes sense.